# How do I share the current loaded URL from webview

Tags: android, webview, share-intent

How do I get and share the current URL in `webview`? My share works but doesn't share the current URL loaded.

Here is my code in `WebView`

```
private String mTrackUrlChange;

private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTrackUrlChange=url;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

       mTrackUrlChange = url;
    }
};
```

For my share:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mTrackUrlChange);
    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mTrackUrlChange);
    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My share works but doesn't share the current URL loaded

You have not explained what that means. However, your code has some problems that may contribute to whatever your problem is.

First, you are building the `Intent` and calling `setShareIntent()` too soon. `mTrackUrlChange` will be `null` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, because your `WebView` will barely have begun loading the Web page. Build the `Intent` and call `setShareIntent()` inside `onPageFinished()`, not inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Beyond that, since you are setting `EXTRA_STREAM`, the extra needs to be a `Uri`, not a `String`, and the MIME type needs to be the MIME type of the actual content (e.g., `text/html` for a Web page). Also, you are calling `setShareIntent()` multiple times, which is not necessary.

Comment: I mean it works but when when I use share, it doesn't contain the URL

Comment: @kielou: Please see the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: it doesn't allow me to call `setShareIntent()` inside `onPageFinished()`

Comment: @kielou: Why not? You will need to make some other changes, such as making `mShare` be a field, rather than a local variable inside of `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.3/ActionBar/ShareNative) demonstrating calling `setShareIntent()` from places other than `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.